# How to add floating back and next buttons to content div?

Tags: html, css

The template I am working with has a container, with content and navigation divs. The code looks something like this:

```
<div id="user_content" class="user_content">
<div class="main_content"> some content, text and whatever else, can be pretty long!</div>
<div class="content_nav">
<div class="col-md-3"><a id="prevB" href="http://google.com">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK!</a></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><a id="nextB" href="http://yahoo.com">CLICK HERE TO GO NEXT!</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

See Figure 1 below for drawing.
[image]

Relevant CSS for the `main_content` div:

```
.main_content {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
    height: auto;
}
```

I can change the PHP to generate the BACK and NEXT links without its own div, so it will look like this:

```
<div id="user_content" class="user_content">
<a id="prevB" href="http://google.com">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK!</a>
<div class="main_content"> some content, text and whatever else, can be pretty long!</div>
<a id="nextB" href="http://yahoo.com">CLICK HERE TO GO NEXT!</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I don't understand is the proper CSS to make the `<a>` BACK and NEXT links to be on the left and right side of the `main_content` container. See Figure 2 below for drawing.

[image]

Here is a link to the JFIDDLE that I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/7wet25zn/

Comment: you have an extra `</div>` inside the *I wish*

Comment: You better assign `.prev` and `.next` to your buttons

Comment: Have you tried using `position:absolute` for your buttons? What have you tried (at all)?

Comment: Can't see CSS you've tried and specific problems you've encountered with it.

Comment: @user2525253 can i see your CSS?

Comment: Updated post to include `main_content` div css. I am lost to what to do with the `<a>` css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your {content} part is tall and  prev and next button should be in the middle of the viewport (not tall div), you may add `display:block; position:fixed; top:50%;` to prev and next links so it will be visible regardless of height of div.

Answer (score 4):

Position `absolute` your anchors at top 50% and subtract 0.5em (half the font-size, or any other value):

```css
.user_content {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  height: 160px;
}
.user_content a {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
}
.user_content a.next {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_content">

  <div class="main_content"></div>

  <a class="prev" href="#!">PREV</a>
  <a class="next" href="#!">NEXT</a>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced a similar problem building tooltips on a page.  It wasn't something I had encountered before and wanted to do it with HTML and CSS.  What ended up working for me was defining a parent container and making the content you want floating like so:

```
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And defining the CSS as such:

```
.parent-container {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;

}
```

This allows you to set width and height on the child class as relative to the position of the parent container.  Good luck!